# Plotting Hough Transform MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing, hough-transform

I was trying to plot hough transform using `hough(edge_detected_image)`. Then Im using the following commands:

```
imshow(h,[],'XData',theta,'YData',rho,'InitialMagnification','fit');
 axis on
 axis normal
 hold on
```

But Im getting the plot as:[image: this]

while i need something like [image: this]

How can this be achieved? Are there any settings to be done?

Answer (score 6):

You need to change the colour map.  In addition, you may want to rescale the data so that it conforms within an acceptable range.  Use [`imadjust`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imadjust.html) on the output accumulator matrix prior to showing it.  You will need to change the values of the accumulator matrix so that it's normalized.  Simply dividing by the maximum value of `h` should work.

The colour map used in your figure is the `hot` colour map, so therefore:

```
imshow(imadjust(h / max(h(:))),'XData',theta,'YData',rho,'InitialMagnification','fit');
axis on; axis normal; hold on
colormap(gca,hot);
```